# Parse a date from an export of a lotus notes base

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, lotus-notes

In a C# application, I have to parse an xml file which is an export of a lotus notes database.

The exports contains dates in this format :

```
<noteinfo noteid='6706' unid='6B6A3ADD41061773C12580F2004E8EB3' sequence='6'>
    <created>
        <datetime dst='true'>20170329T161803,39+02</datetime>
    </created>
    <modified>
        <datetime>20171108T100439,39+01</datetime>
    </modified>
    <revised>
        <datetime>20171108T100439,38+01</datetime>
    </revised>
    <lastaccessed>
        <datetime>20171108T100439,38+01</datetime>
    </lastaccessed>
    <addedtofile>
        <datetime dst='true'>20170329T163711,21+02</datetime>
    </addedtofile>
</noteinfo>
```

I have to extract these dates into a .Net Datetime value.

However, I don't get what's this format. Trying to parse the date fails:

```
var created = DateTime.Parse("20170329T161803,39+02");
```

Throws

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

How to parse this date format ?

The first part of the date, before the comma, is obvious. The second part is less. `+02` probably match the GMT+02 timezone, but I don't get the `39`

PS: I don't have control on the exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `,39` are the milliseconds

```
var created = DateTime.ParseExact("20170329T161803,38+02", "yyyyMMddTHHmmss,ffz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Reference: [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks! it works as expected. You are probably right, ,39 should be the ms. And actually, the precision does not have to be more precise than the minutes.

Comment: It's hundredths of a second, not milliseconds, but you've got the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var created = DateTime.ParseExact("20170329T161803,39+02".Remove(15), "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I'm not sure what the `,39+02` is in terms of a time - zone perhaps? I trimmed it off, but if you can describe what it is maybe it can be parsed

Edit:

Assuming that's milliseconds and timezone:

```
var created = DateTime.ParseExact("20170329T161803,39+02", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss','ffz",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: As I said, +02 match the GMT+02 timezone , which is where the customer DB lives. I assume it has to be kept to be exact.